# asp.net 5 class library for Linux

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget-package

I want to build a Class Library in ASP.NET 5 using VS2015, but as far as I can tell it only produces DLL files. These would then be packages as a Nuget package.

But does this mean that these DLL's would also work fine on a Linux environment? Or do I need to do something else in order to build a Nuget package that will also work on Linux?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you select the Class Library (Package) option under the Web node in the New Project window.

That will create a project that outputs a dll in a NuGet package